# Issue with vertical alignment of UML elements from PlantUML

Tags: plantuml

I cannot align namespaces/classes vertically in PlantUML output. E.g.:

```
@startuml
namespace AAA {

    class MyBaseClass {
    }

    class MyDerivedClass {
    }

    MyBaseClass <|-- MyDerivedClass
}

namespace BBB {
    class OtherClass {
    }

    class YetAnotherClass {
    }

    OtherClass  <|-- YetAnotherClass
}

AAA ---down---> BBB

hide circle
@enduml
```

[image: Output:]

Is there a way to get namespace BBB under AAA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get namespace BBB under AAA?

It's possible with `left to right direction` (but it's not easy to maintain, since left is up, etc.):

```
@startuml
left to right direction
hide circle
hide empty members

namespace BBB {
    class OtherClass {
    }

    class YetAnotherClass {
    }

    OtherClass  <|-left- YetAnotherClass
}

namespace AAA {

    class MyBaseClass {
    }

    class MyDerivedClass {
    }

    MyBaseClass <|-left- MyDerivedClass
}

'AAA -> BBB

@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: ` 'AAA->BBB` is commented out, how would it be possible to have a line going from the bottom of `AAA` to the top of `BBB`?

Comment: @albert Here's the best I could come up with in the time I have https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/VP0zhi8m48JxFSLsht9Ey8HYGuke4Q88za8i-GVP2oW2xewL58IWuChMV9ePJvsvINpn3luS7HavOhAdbj7OH9fj3D1QGwXjqew6E_apT-Z97oXb0C1oj6joHYbbjUvKasdPl--zzln6LfJibSmifPIgDjnI-abiYMM8CzYun_z3c7WB0Z-J1t2KymOdrW2Jpc9NfZ0KzaOiHWvGleTYy2X2AGar1LFsVG40